# Как получить кол-во всех нужных тегов из Веб Элемента. TypeScript

Tags: typescript, test-automation

К примеру, у меня есть такой div:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, в этом диве есть еще 3 дива, задача в том, чтобы получить именно это количество, подскажите, как это реализовать? Как правильно написать функцию для данного действия? Вот что я имею, но оно не работает

```
public async getRows(id: string): Promise<WebdriverIO.ElementArray> {
  return (await $$(tableNameFirst+ id + tableNameLast));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Плюс минус вот так.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>111</div>
  <div>222</div>
  <div>333</div>
  <span>4444</span>
</div>
```

```
const func = (id: string): HTMLDivElement[] => {
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (!el) return [];
  return Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('div'));
}

const divElements = func('wrapper');
```